# How to identify the doctrine query on mysql logs?

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, symfony

How can I identify in the MySQL logs (slow logs, process list, etc) the function/method that invoqued or executed a query that was created with Doctrine, either with Query Builder and DQL? The project is being developed in Symfony, but has other parts in perl and in PHP without symfony.

In some parts of our project, for example in perl, we just add comments to the query. For example:

```
SELECT /* FooScript-FooMethod */ col1, col2 FROM  TABLE t1 WHERE col1 >= '2016-01-08'
```

Is there any way to do it with Doctrine? I mean, can I add comments to the generated query in Doctrine, or put extra info on the query so that it can be identified outside the doctrine logs?

Answer (score 0):

How about... [Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)?

In common ancestor of your Repository classes in the method `createQueryBuilder` do:

```php
public function createQueryBuilder($alias, $indexBy = null)
{
    $qb = parent::createQueryBuilder($alias, $indexBy);

    if (DOCTRINE_DEBUG) {
        $qb->andWhere("'DEBUG_MARKER' != ':DEBUG_MARKER'")
           ->setParameter('DEBUG_MARKER', '');
    }

    return $qb; // D-oh!
}
```

Then when building the query:

```php
    ...
    $qb->setParameter('DEBUG_MARKER', __METHOD__);
    // but that assumes there IS a **DEBUG_MARKER** parameter
    ...
```

Or add a `setDebugMarker` method in QueryBuilder...

Answer (score -1):

As per the MySQL documentation, there are different types of logs which help you in managing MySQL server. As per you case, you require a `slow query logs` and `general logs`(to see the query fired by any client).

These type of logs which I mentioned are disabled by default by the MySQL. To check logs are enabled or not, run the following query and see the results:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%log%';
```

In the returned results search for following variables:

```
slow_query_log  
general_log
```

If value for these variable is `OFF`,which means that logs are not enabled in MySQL server yet.

Best way to enable `Logs` is to set these variables in MySQL config(my.cnf), which may be located at `/etc/my.cnf`(in Linux) and this location can be different which depends upon your MySQL installation.

**Setting up Logs Variables in Config:**

Add following in `[mysqld]` section of config :

```
[mysqld]
slow_query_log=ON
slow_query_log_file=/opt/mysql/stage-slow.log #path to slow logs

#General Log: Logs each  SQL query statement received from clients

general_log= ON
general_log_file=/opt/mysql/stage.log #path to general query logs
```

After updating the config with theses variables you need to start MySQL services to take effect.

Run `service mysqld restart`(linux only) to Restart MySQL services.

Comment: My problem is not on identifying the configuring the mysql logs. Slow query log is active, but not the general log.
My question is "How to identify the doctrine query on mysql logs?".

I've added a bit more clarification on the question.